# Median between Top/Bottom 5?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a sheet that shows debit spending. I've split out the spending model by top/bottom 3 months this year in terms of my net balance (credits-debits).

I have reference lines to auto-adjust based on which type of description(purchase locations) and display median purchase amount.

I want aggregate the median for an item on top 3 and then also for bottom 3. Then, I want to get the difference between those median figures between top 3 months and bottom 3 months.

So if rite aid median spending is $5 for bottom 3 months, and $3 for top three months, I want to find the difference (+$2)

so, syntax-wise I'd need it to: Sum(description debits of top 3 months net balance)-sum(description debits of bottom 3 months net balance)

Comment: Have you already written the calculation for top and bottom 3?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have top and bottom rank calculations already done, you can start by creating the rank:

```
TopRank = Rank(Sum([NetBalance]),desc)
BottomRank = Rank(Sum([NetBalance]),asc)
```

Then you can use these two ranks to calculate the difference measure:

```
DesiredCalc = SUM(IF [TopRank]<=3 then 1 else 0 end) - SUM(IF [BottomRank]<=3 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Note: If the above calculation doesn't work you can try splitting them into different calculated fields

Comment: how do I set those strings as a rank? I get an error in my calc field when I structure it like that

Comment: Syntax error: missing an operator?

`topRank = Rank(sum([Diff (Credit-Debit)]),desc)`

`Bottomrank = rank(sum([Diff (Credit-Debit)]),asc)`

Comment: Is Diff (Credit-Debit) the name of the calculated measure?

Comment: If Diff (Credit-Debit) is already aggregated, you can try removing the sum. topRank = Rank([Diff (Credit-Debit)],desc)